# Elixir one function to convert both floats and integers to bitstrings?

Tags: types, erlang, numbers, bitstring, elixir

Does Elixir have a function that accepts integers and floats and converts them to strings?

I need something like this:

```
a = 3
b = 3.14
number_to_binary(a)
% => "3"
number_to_binary(b)
% => "3.14"
```

Is there a function in Elixir that already does something like this? I looked at the docs and didn't see anything. I also checked the Erlang docs and didn't see any functions like this either.

Comment: If you are using Ecto it'll convert integers to floats for you. Use `Model.changeset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each one of the types, there is a function:

- http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/Kernel.html#integer_to_binary/1
- http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/Kernel.html#float_to_binary/1

If you want a general `number_to_binary` function, try simply using `inspect` (that is `Kernel.inspect`, not `IO.inspect`).

```
a = 3
b = 3.14
inspect a
% => "3"
inspect b
```

Answer (score 21):

You can also use [to_string](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#to_string/1) for this purpose:

```
iex(1)> to_string(3)
"3"
iex(2)> to_string(3.14)
"3.14"
```

Or string interpolation:

```
iex(3)> "#{3.14}"
"3.14"
iex(4)> "#{3}"
"3"
```

If you really want a function that converts only numbers, and raises if anything else is given, you can define your own:

```
defmodule Test do
  def number_to_binary(x) when is_number(x), do: to_string(x)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

inspect does this

```
iex(1)> inspect(3)
"3"
iex(2)> inspect(3.14)
"3.14"
iex(3)> a = inspect(3.14)
"3.14"
iex(4)> a
"3.14"
```